# How i can get number of GOOGLE_VOICE Contact in contact content provider

Tags: android

**This is the code to get normal type and I want to get GOOGLE_VOICE contact number**

```
int PhoneType = curPhone.getInt(curPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

 numbers = curPhone.getString(curPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


switch (PhoneType) {
case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
homeNumber = numbers;
break;}
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: I need to get this type of contact number GOOGLE_VOICE, the code above is work good but can't find any type to (GOOGLE_VOICE)
you can read more about it from here 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/field

Comment: there is no API for Google Voice as of 2019 so i don't thing you can access and why not to try Content provider ?

Comment: I am already using Content provider, but can't find any way to get it

Comment: your only task is to get contect or it must be from Google voice ?

Comment: yes I just want to get the contact number that has GOOGLE_VOICE Tag